# What can I leave out when creating an executable JRuby jar?

Tags: ruby, jar, jruby

I've attached an image of what **JRuby.jar** contains:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/fbfd966375.png

The problem is that even for simple scripts, the resulting jars have about 8mb. Can you tell me which folders I could remove from there, and still have it running ... or what's the purpose of some of that folders?

Comment: Seeing as how just the lib/ruby/1.8 folder of my Ruby 1.8 install is about 7mb I wouldn't view the 8mb jar as excessive. However, perhaps this thread might be of some use: Minimal jruby jar http://archive.codehaus.org/lists/org.codehaus.jruby.user/msg/364b5a7c0905160639m2145a248gabf27cee52a73af9@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [repackaging the jar with pack200](http://markmail.org/thread/pbupfy7fdwgqxfzc) if you just want a better compression ratio.

JRuby does bundle all its dependent Java libraries, so it won't be easy to trim those back. Stay tuned or follow progress on JRuby for Android for a more minimal jar.